# magento upgrade error from 1.12 to 1.13 SQLSTATE: able not foundcatalog_category_flat’ doesn’t exist

Tags: magento

I have added patch file of Magento Enteprise 1.13.0.0 to my Magento Enteprise 1.12.0.2 
    An getting eorrr 
    SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table ‘catalog_category_flat’ doesn’t exist 
    And also done changes to tables as directed by http://www.hassmann-software.de/mysql-workbench-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-after-600-seconds/ but still getting same error. I am not able open any admin page.

And also posted this question at [Magento Answers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/answers/upgrade-error-from-1.12-to-1.13-SQLSTATE-able-not-foundcatalog_category_flat-doesnt-exist)

[image: Magento Error]

Comment: catalog_category_flat error solved after doing innodb as shown in http://www.hassmann-software.de/mysql-workbench-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-after-600-seconds/ but now getting or view already exists: 1050 Table 'enterprise_index_multiplier' already exists

Comment: Going out on a limb here... do you remember how you solve that enterprise_index_multiplier already exists ? It's puzzling me !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
DELETE
FROM catalog_category_entity_datetime
WHERE catalog_category_entity_datetime.attribute_id NOT IN (
    SELECT eav_attribute.attribute_id FROM eav_entity_type
     INNER JOIN eav_attribute ON eav_attribute.entity_type_id = eav_entity_type.entity_type_id
     WHERE (eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='catalog_category')
);

DELETE
FROM catalog_category_entity_decimal
WHERE catalog_category_entity_decimal.attribute_id NOT IN (
    SELECT eav_attribute.attribute_id FROM eav_entity_type
     INNER JOIN eav_attribute ON eav_attribute.entity_type_id = eav_entity_type.entity_type_id
     WHERE (eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='catalog_category')
);
DELETE
FROM catalog_category_entity_int
WHERE catalog_category_entity_int.attribute_id NOT IN (
    SELECT eav_attribute.attribute_id FROM eav_entity_type
     INNER JOIN eav_attribute ON eav_attribute.entity_type_id = eav_entity_type.entity_type_id
     WHERE (eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='catalog_category')
);

DELETE
FROM catalog_category_entity_text
WHERE catalog_category_entity_text.attribute_id NOT IN (
    SELECT eav_attribute.attribute_id FROM eav_entity_type
     INNER JOIN eav_attribute ON eav_attribute.entity_type_id = eav_entity_type.entity_type_id
     WHERE (eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='catalog_category')
);

DELETE
FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar
WHERE catalog_category_entity_varchar.attribute_id NOT IN (
    SELECT eav_attribute.attribute_id FROM eav_entity_type
     INNER JOIN eav_attribute ON eav_attribute.entity_type_id = eav_entity_type.entity_type_id
     WHERE (eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='catalog_category')
);



SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_datetime;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_decimal;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_int;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_text;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_varchar;
TRUNCATE TABLE core_url_rewrite;
```

Comment: This query delete all the categories information and it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: have you tried, only duplicate category are deleted, i have tested and successfully upgraded to enterprise 1.13.0.2 as 1.13.0.0 required several fixes.